# How to get a rectangular theme with no grid in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = structure(list(Date = structure(c(11690, 11725, 11753, 11781, 
11809, 11844, 11872, 11942, 11970, 11998, 12026, 12061, 12089, 
12117, 12145, 12180, 12208, 12243, 12299, 12327, 12362, 12390, 
12425, 12453, 12481, 12509, 12544, 12572, 12600, 12663), class = "Date"), 
    Sentiment = c(-0.010752688172043, 0.0375, 0.0317460317460317, 
    0.0280373831775701, 0.019047619047619, 0.0280373831775701, 
    0.0253164556962025, 0, -0.025, 0.00684931506849315, -0.010989010989011, 
    -0.032258064516129, -0.0149253731343284, -0.0172413793103448, 
    -0.0761904761904762, 0, -0.00555555555555556, 0.0178571428571429, 
    0.00632911392405063, 0.0217391304347826, 0.088, 0.0344827586206897, 
    0.0130718954248366, 0.0112359550561798, -0.0164835164835165, 
    0.00420168067226891, 0.0401785714285714, 0.0338983050847458, 
    0.0376344086021505, 0.0178571428571429)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I plot it using `plot` I get the rectangular theme with no grid as below:[image]

However, I cannot find the equivalent theme using `ggplot`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'rectangular scheme'?

Comment: @user438383 I edited the question, please refer to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Sentiment)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `theme_classic()` has the shape of only half-rectanlge. I want to have a full rectanlge

Comment: You can add that by hand with `theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA))`. I don't know if there's a theme that has that built int tho. Check my edit :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful! I'll mark it as correct when SO allows me to do so:)